# A terminal that is always scrollable or forever like less?

Tags: terminal, less, scrolling

I'm currently using #!Waldorf, but have used Manjaro, Mint, Ubunto, Fedora, etc.

Is there a way to make my terminal always behave like it's passed to less but without the (END) "feature" that requires I quit before I type anymore text.

What I'm looking for, is a terminal that always supports scrolling left,right, up and down with the keyboard... and "No, SHIFT+PgUp and SHIFT+PgDn are not the same thing".

The command `less` allows for a "natural" scrolling as if I were viewing the terminal's output inside of a window.

Clearly the ability to detect when output has exceeded the current viewport's width and height exist, does anyone know how to incorporate this into the terminal itself?

Comment: seems like the obvious answer to the question is `less`. Less obvious is `cat`.

Comment: but this then requires that I  pipe every command through less.. and is that even possible? I know enough of nix to be dangerous, but am nowhere near a power user

Comment: Have a look at `man less`.

Comment: so you don't want the up/down arrows to cycle through history? Maybe you can rebind them to move through scrollback with something like kitty?
If you want powerful on-demand editing through vi, check this out: https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/qqf4nn/psa_you_can_use_neovim_as_the_kitty_terminal/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of anything that allows for left and right scrolling; however, tmux allows you to scroll up and down using the keyboard.

There are others like it. You might consider screen and byobu as well. They are all much more than keyboard terminal scrolling, but as far as I know, they all have that feature.